# Is there a Term::ANSIScreen equivalent for Python?

Tags: python, ansi-escape, ansi-colors

Perl has the excellent module `Term::ANSIScreen` for doing all sorts of fancy cursor movement and terminal color control. I'd like to reimplement a program that's currently in Perl in Python instead, but the terminal ANSI colors are key to its function. Is anyone aware of an equivalent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only need colors You may want to borrow the implementation from pygments. IMO it's much cleaner than the one from ActiveState

http://dev.pocoo.org/hg/pygments-main/file/b2deea5b5030/pygments/console.py

Comment: great, glad you liked it. Thanks for the best answer!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [cookbook recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/574451/) on ActiveState to get you started.  It covers colors and positioning.

*[Edit: The pygments code submitted above by Jorge Vargas is a better approach. ]*

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I just have to bundle it up in to a nice module and clean up the code a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the [termcolor](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor) and the [termstyle](https://github.com/gfxmonk/termstyle) packages. The latter is capable of disabling colour output if stdout is not a terminal.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python).

Answer (score 2):

While I haven't used it myself, I believe the curses library is commonly used for this:

http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html

And the How-to:

http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html#curses-howto

Unfortunatly, this module doesn't appear to be available in the standard library for windows.
This site apparently has a windows solution:

http://adamv.com/dev/python/curses/

Comment: Not quite the same I think. You need to make a "window" with curses, whereas with Term::ANSIScreen I can print an arbitrary number of lines to the terminal using the standard print function.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't look like it's meant to deal with the current terminal.  It looks like Jeff may have what your looking for.